# UIImageView subclass duplicate the image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview

I am working on a subclass of UIImageView and one of the things I require is when the object is initalised with the initWithImage: message a 'copy' is created.

I must be confusing something because I can't see what is not working here..

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
[image retain];
if (self = [super initWithImage:image]) {

    if (!maskImage) {
        maskImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];
        if (maskImage != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Made mask image");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }
        //maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
}

[image release];
return self;
}
```

There are no errors when I build this and the maskimage does appear to be created (i do not get the failure message).  However, if I uncomment the line allocating from a png it works.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from this question what problem you're encountering. What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: OK sorry, I am having trouble debugging the issue..
I have a uiimage category that changes pixel values in the mask image.  This works using the commented out maskImage line but does not using the maskImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];

I'm suspicous of the category actually causing this issue as the crash I am getting is related to bad memory access.

Answer (score 1):

You should retain created image, in example like this:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image]) {
        if (!maskImage) {
                maskImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]] retain];
                if (maskImage != nil) {                
                        NSLog(@"Made mask image");
                } else {
                        NSLog(@"Failed");
                }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should work.

```
- (id)initWithImage:(NSString *)image {
if (self = [super initWithImage:image]) {

        if (!maskImage) {
                img = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
                maskImage = CGImageRetain(img.CGImage);
                if (maskImage != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"Made mask image");
                } else {
                        NSLog(@"Failed");
                }
        }
}

return self;
}
```

1. Changes

   - pass NSString instead of image
   - no need to retain/release image
   - need to define img, maskImage in .h
   - maskImage in .h should have retain property set in @property ( e.g.
     @property (nonatomic, retain))

Comment: Just a nit-picky note, but you might want to consider naming the -(id) initWithImage:  method to something along the lines of initWithImageNamed:  The way it is written leads me to think that the method would take a UIImage as a parameter, not a NSString with the name of the image file.

Comment: Yep, on the fly copy/paste code from his example, but would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set maskImage to nil, to make sure it isn't garbage:

```
self.maskImage=nil;
```

That may screwing up your line (if not now, then later):

```
if(!imaskImage)
```

Then, to make a copy, just implement NSCopying in a UIImage subclass. It's easy to do. Then you can type:

```
maskImage = [image copy];
```

Alternatively, you can convert the image to data, archive, then unarchive, then convert back to a UIImage. This gives you a complete copy of the image. It's a little more complex, but its the same method used for making deep copies of an object graph.